# What is the busbar rating in my main service panel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, solar, electric-vehicle

I don't understand the difference between "device rating" and "meter socket rating" on my MSP?  I'm most interesting in the busbar rating?

[image]

Here are pictures of MSP:

https://lemonsolar.cqrivertech.com/PanelStickers/#single:MSP.jpeg

https://lemonsolar.cqrivertech.com/MSPPanel/#single:248907BF-63EF-4802-8326-47753EB78BD1.jpeg

https://lemonsolar.cqrivertech.com/MSPPanel/#single:9E448259-31B3-4B85-934E-2957C4C2C8FD.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

### Panel inventory vs solar

This is a typical "Class 320" 400A service panel, in "all-in-one" format.

These panels typically have one 200A breaker feeding a built-in "subpanel" for branch circuit breakers -- and yours does exactly that.  The bus rating of this internal "subpanel" is 200A and its breaker is 200A.  **This allows 40A solar**.   *I infer that because the Accessory schedule shows a Lug Kit 2-300kcmil **(200A MAX)** ECLK 2 **225**.  The catalog number gives away the fact that the subfeed lug kit is actually rated 225A, yet they feel the need to include the note (200A MAX) to debunk any notion that the lug kit could be used at 225A.*

Note that a 150A breaker is optional; that would allow **90A solar**. NEC requires that the feeder breaker size *be sufficient for the loads to be served* as calculated in a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation. Based on the loads I see in there today, I am sure it would easily fit on a 150A breaker.  Installing the 150A breaker would require a meter pull from the power company; they'll be happy to turn it **off** but may want to see a permit and inspection before they turn it back **on**.  The magic words are probably "defective main breaker" since repairs don't need a permit LOL.

The West Garage Subpanel appears to be fed by a 100A breaker. The part number reveals it to be a 100A panel ("1100" = 1-phase 100A) supporting 20A of solar, **except I think, the next line says "Ratings: 125A Maximum"** (can't really tell due to the low resolution) but if it does say that, then it's a 125A panel allowing **50A of solar**.

The "Wok Kitchen Subpanel" appears to be fed by a 100A breaker.  The part number definitely shows it is a 125A rated subpanel.  As such it can support **50A of solar** also.

### Ways to get there

You mention in comments ambitions for 20kW solar.

One of your experts suggested changing one of the subpanels from 125A bus to 225A bus.  That's brilliant.  That's exactly what to do.   That will get you to 19.2kW solar in that panel, and I'm guessing you'll call that "close enough" LOL.

Otherwise you'll need to have multiple arrays feeding different panels with the limits I stated above.  Noting that a 125% derate is needed for solar, so 50A of solar breaker actually means an inverter rated for 40A.   Dividing like this won't be difficult since you're using microinverters mounted on the panels themselves - it's not like you'll have to buy additional grid-tie inverters.

### On EV charging

The vast majority of would-be EV owners *wildly overestimate* their AC power requirements. Technology Connections devoted a whole video to debunking the "50A myth" and showing how easy it is - [we regularly cite it here. I'll cue it up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iyp_X3mwE1w&t=1695s).

However, even worse, people think that if they get 2 EVs they will need *double the power* or triple, with 3!  Actually, the opposite is true - the more EVs you have, the **less** power you need!  Well, almost.

When you propose that a 20A circuit is sufficient and 30A is plenty, some will fight for the extreme corner case of having *two, 250 mile days in a row, with only 8 hours to charge and with no access to DC fast charging*.  But even they admit: in a 2-car family *that's not going to happen **on both cars at once***.

A win/win is created via a technology called **Power Sharing**. Several EV wall charging units can be linked, and assigned an allowed ampacity **To Share**. They will dynamically share based on the number of cars plugged in and their needs. Thus, full circuit power is being poured into one car or the other.   If the 3 cars need 30, 50 and 250 miles respectively, the supply *will* be pouring 30 miles per hour into one car or the other, and they'll all be done in 10.7 hours.

And here's the tricky part: this time period starts when the first car arrives, and finishes when the last one leaves.  So it's really not a problem.

And regardless, the other two cars can just not plug in that day, or, set their timers to start charging at 6 AM when the needy car has had all evening to charge.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, you are correct, I'm in the process of evaluating multiple solar panel project bids. Someone actually mentioned I have 400A buspar in MSP, I doubted it so I posted here for suggestions.

Comment: Anyway, going back to solar project.  I'm getting a relatively large system (20KW system of 50 panels of either REC Alpha Pure Black 400 or Panasonic EverVolt 400) with Enphase Microinverter 8M.  I'm having trouble to understand the interconnection.

Comment: Derating MSP to 150A is not ideal as I will have 2-3 EVs and a pool heat pump to add in near future (which is 50% of reasons behind solar project).  Line-side tap is not recommended due to cost.  Someone mentioned load-side tap, not sure how it works.  Other recommended adding subpanel with a larger busbar.

Comment: BTW, if you are solar installer (not sure if you are), do you think there’s any advantage to consider SolarEdge system in my case (of larger PV system)?

Comment: again, thank you for your suggestions.  I actually have two subpanels, each on 100A breaker in MSP.  Each subpanel has 125 busbar.  Because changing out subpanel is expensive ($4000 I've be quoted).  I was offered another solution without “derating” or load-side taps: backfeed PV breaker to the exisiting 100A busbar that’s feeding into the subpanel and re-route wires to subpanel to 200A main busbar.  Will this work?

Answer (score 0):

The "device rating" and "meter socket rating" here are both 400A (320A continuous). In other words, you have a box that can handle 400A/320A, which is the largest typical residential service.

The "service disconnect" is commonly referred to as the "main breaker". That is the largest breaker that can be installed for the breaker panel. In this case, it is, as is typical, 200A.

There is an additional 200A max. service disconnect above the breaker panel, which is for feeding another panel. As far as I can tell, the diagram indicates that should have only one breaker, but it appears you have 2 - "GARAGE" on the left and "UT"(?) on the right. That may be a violation of the manufacturer's instructions,, but I am not 100% sure.

Fortunately, information [is available on this page](https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/us/Catalog/Product/?mlfb=US2%3AJA3042B1400SC). It includes a link to "Service & Support (Manuals, Certificates, FAQs...)" which in turn gets to a high-resolution PDF of the wiring diagram. But which unfortunately doesn't seem to state any busbar rating.

Lacking any specific additional information, the busbar rating will at a minimum match the rating of the service disconnect = **200A**.

Comment: both subpanels stickers showing "Rating: 125A maximum", it means subpanel busbars are 125A?  https://lemonsolar.cqrivertech.com/PanelStickers/